# Make an std::map with a coordinate as key

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stdmap

It seems impossible to create an std::map with a coordinate as key. When (x+y+z) is the same for both coordinates, the map just overrides the previous one. Example:

```
map[Coordinate(1, 0, 0)] = object1;
map[Coordinate(0, 1, 0)] = object2;
map[Coordinate(0, 0, 1)] = object3;
```

This will result in there being a std::map with 1 element, which contains `object3` as value and `Coordinate(0, 0, 1)` as key. How can I prevent this so it'll contain all values?

```
#pragma once

struct Coordinate {
    double x, y, z;
    Coordinate(double x, double y, double z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}

    bool operator<(const Coordinate& coord) const {
     if(x + y + z < coord.x + coord.y + coord.z)
        return true;
     return false;
    }

    bool operator==(const Coordinate& coord) const {
        if(x == coord.x && y == coord.y && z == coord.z)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    inline bool isInRange(Coordinate coord, int range) const {
        if(pow(coord.x - this->x, 2) + pow(coord.y - this->y, 2) + pow(coord.z - this->z, 2) <= range*range)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380567/can-i-use-an-stl-map-if-i-plan-to-use-arbitrary-class-objects-as-the-key
read answers

Comment: Your problem is your `<` operator must be deterministic.  The way you have it written `(x + y + z < coord.x + coord.y + coord.z)` it will treat (0,0,1), (0,1,0), and (1,0,0) as equal.

Comment: That's because they are equal when using the 1 dimensional < operator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ - std::map Alternative that doesn't require casting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911963/c-stdmap-alternative-that-doesnt-require-casting)

Comment: See the duplicate I linked. The title might seem weird, but the question is fundamentally the same.

Comment: @Binero If they're indeed equal, then the `map` is working the way it is intended to. IMHO, summing the coordinates for comparison seems a bit odd; you probably want to do something more along the lines of `return std::tie(x,y,z) < std::tie(coord.x, coord.y, coord.z);` instead.

Comment: @Praetorian But they are essentially equal if they are casted to 1 dimension, which is the problem.

Comment: What does casting to 1 dimension mean?

Comment: @NeilKirk Convert the coordinates in a 3 dimensional grid to a point in a 1D grid. (X, Y, Z -> D)

Comment: Then create a custom MapCompare function for your map.

Comment: @NeilKirk How about an std::unordered_map?

Comment: @Binero that's not true. These are not all equal when projected onto the 1D x axis

Comment: @wlyles They aren't projected on the 1D X axis. They are projected on a totally different axis that's not even in the 3D grid.

Comment: I have never used unordered_map before so I don't know if it's suitable. I have used maps with "multiple" keys before using the techniques shown here. It works.

Comment: @Binero Like I said before, if they're *essentially equal* the functionality you're getting is the only one possible. About using `unordered_map`, what would you do differently? You'll need to implement `operator==`, but is that not going to compare equal for `(1,0,0)` and `(0,1,0)`? If you implement it that way, then given your current `operator<` you'll be violating total ordering for your class; which may or may not cause trouble, but it certainly is unintuitive.

Comment: `std::map` is an __ordered__ container. You have to decide what _ordering_ means for your data type. It there is none then find a different container. A `std::unordered_map` will require a _hash_ function and a way to determine _equality_ of hash keys.

Comment: @Praetorian the `==` and `!=` operators do not require me converting it to 1 dimension though.

Comment: @Binero We keep going around in circles here. You're free to implement operators that behave any way you want. But if you do that, you'll have `(1,0,0) == (0,1,0)` comparing false, and `!(((1,0,0) < (0,1,0)) && ((0,1,0) < (1,0,0)))` comparing true. That's unintuitive behavior.

Comment: @Praetorian In my opinion that makes total sense. If you are comparing coordinates like that you expect it to convert it to 1 dimension, and the obvious thing to do is to compare it to the origin. You are basically adding a magic value to it which causes 2 objects to be greater than or less than for no logic reason. Just because the one is more to the top and the other one more to the bottom?

Comment: A [lexicographical ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) is the usual way to compare tuples such as this, though it appears that you wish to do so otherwise. If `(0,0,1) == (0,1,0)` should be `true` for you, but the coordinates are considered unique, you should probably use an [`std::unordered_map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/) and create a deterministic hash function

Answer (score 8):

> « std::map is a sorted associative container that contains key-value
>   pairs with **unique keys**. Keys are sorted by using the comparison
>   function Compare. » from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

The default comparison function is [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) which will use the operator< on the `Key` objects.

Thus, the problem lies in the `operator<` of `Coordinate` :

```
bool operator<(const Coordinate& coord) const {
 if(x + y + z < coord.x + coord.y + coord.z)
    return true;
 return false;
}
```

`(1, 0, 0) < (0, 1, 0)` is false but `(0, 1, 0) < (1, 0, 0)` is also false, so as far as `std::map` is concerned, `(1, 0, 0) == (0, 1, 0)`.

In order to use `Coordinate` objects as keys in a `std::map`, you'll need to find the correct strict weak ordering criterion (the `operator<`) that meets your needs.

As other said, you could use something like [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) (in C++11) which will first compare `x`, then `y` then `z` like this :

```
bool operator<(const Coordinate& coord) const {
    if(x < coord.x) return true;
    if(x > coord.x) return false;
    //x == coord.x
    if(y < coord.y) return true;
    if(y > coord.y) return false;
    //x == coord.x && y == coord.y
    if(z < coord.z) return true;
    if(z > coord.z) return false;
    //*this == coord
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That's a good explanation of the problem. For bonus points, can you suggest a better ordering?

Comment: Though ordering of coordinates doesn't really make sense, one could use std::tie(x,y,z) < std::tie(coord.x, coord.y, coord.z) to achieve strict ordering.

Answer (score 2):

Your operator < must work so that all possible coordinates can be placed in a stable order. If you add the values then there are several combinations of coordinate that are indistinguishable from each other.

Try this

```
friend bool operator < (const Coordinate& left, const Coordinate& right)
{
    if (left.z < right.z)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (right.z < left.z)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (left.y < right.y)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (right.y < left.y)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (left.x < right.x)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else /* (right.x < left.x) */
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't what it should return though. This is basically tricking the map.

Comment: Or in C++11, `return std::tie(l.x,l.y,l.z) < std::tie(r.x,r.y,r.z);`

Comment: @MikeSeymour I haven't seen that before.

Comment: @Binero what should it return? What does c1 < c2 actually mean? You don't have to use operator <, that is just the default. The linked question in the comments shows how to use a custom function.

Comment: @Binero then don't override the operator, make this a custom compare function and pass it to the set (AKA `friend bool CustomCompare(const Coordinate& left, const Coordinate& right){...}` and construct `map<Coordinate,foo,CustomCompare> map`

Comment: @MadScienceDreams at the moment an unordered_map seems more sensible to use. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @Binero ah this thread got away from me. Be wary of hashing (or keying at all really) with doubles, though: floating-point errors could really screw you up (you could do smarter keying in C++11 to combat this). And some unrelated points could hash to be equal (the probability is low but not non-existent)

Answer (score -1):

For the purposes of comparison, a `std::map` will regard two objects `a` and `b` as the same if `!(a < b) && !(b < a)`. Your `operator<` creates precisely such ambiguities. First you insert with `(1, 0, 0)` as the key. Next you are inserting, and thus comparing, `(0, 1, 0)`. However, with the operator as you have it, `(1, 0, 0) < (0, 1, 0)` returns `false`, and so does `(0, 1, 0) < (1, 0, 0)`, thus both coordinates map to the same key.

Comment: So there is no way to fix it without 'hacking' the functionality?

Comment: @Binero Come up with an order for them, such that all coordinates can be strictly ordered. For instance, say that if the sum of all components is equal, then the one with biggest `x` is greater, next comes one with `y` if those are equal, and last comes one with the biggest `z`